# Using environment variable With Post/Session?

Tags: etl, informatica

I'm using the environment variable $PMTargetName@numAffectedRow,  but the TargetName is a parameter(parfile)

I'm trying to do this way:

$PM$$SOURCE_TABLE@NumAffectedRows

Is not working :/

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use here is the name of the `Target Transformation`, not the table name. So assuming you've got a `Target Transformation` named `MyTargetTable` and you use the `Target Table Name` property to set the actual table name to e.g. `Customers`, then:

- `$PMMyTargetTable@TableName` should give you `Customers`
- and `$PMMyTargetTable@NumAffectedRows` should get you what you're looking for

Comment: I have three targets.

In parameter file we have the following out variable:

$OutputFileName and to each target add the extension for example:

$OutputFileName.resval
$OutputFileName.out
$OutputFileName,rej

Comment: I have to do this way ?
${PMOutputFileName.resval}@numAffectedRow ??

Comment: $OutputFileName is the name of the target File. You need to use the name of Transformation. Edit the session, go to Mapping tab and check the name on the list which is on the left side.

Comment: Yes, but i wanna to put the Target Table Name as parameter variable. Some like that -> $PM$$SOURCE_TABLE@NumAffectedRows. is it possible ?

Comment: I'd need a screenshot of your problem. You are using a parameter for a Target Table Name - that's fine. I'm asking you to use Transformation Name, not the target table name. Can you see the difference? Show me a screenshot of your sessions 'mapping' tab, and I'll point it out.

Comment: Let'go haha. I have three targets and I'm using this line command in post success session -> `echo $PMShortcut_to_f_DS_ODS_PER_0006_PE0@numAffectedRows`. I'd like to know if the target name 'Shortcut_to_f_DS_ODS_PER_0006_PE0' can be a parameter of the parameter file ?

Answer (score 0):

The variables to be used in pre/post session commands need to be passed to the session from parameter file. e.g. $PMTargetName should be used in your session e.g. as Target Table Name. If you are doing this, then this will work - ${PMTargetName}@numAffectedRow. Adding parentheses will ensure your variable is expanded before @numAffectedRow is appended to it.

If you are not using $PMTargetName anywhere in your session then IS will not expand it. You should declare it as your workflow variable. And since you have already defined it in parameter file...rest should work.